# C# Monitor missing file

Tags: c#

I'm working with a C# application with some lib as dll. When I run app as debug, it throw:

> FileNotFoundException The specified
>   module could not be found. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

The problem: Exception is not show which file is missing. I tried to find in stack track but have no luck. Is there anyway, include 3rd software can monitor this?

Comment: There may be an InnerException with more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from [SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx) to see in detail which file the process tries and fails to load. 
This application (and the whole suite of tools) is free.